# How do I give chromium permissions to read files of my /usr or /tmp folders?

Tags: chromium

I installed chromium browser from the snap store and it works fine except when I try to run jupyter notebooks from some locations, it will raise a permission denied error and I don't know how to fix it. Firefox runs it fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chromium, you need to allow it to access files on local storage.
Simply go to the *Ubuntu Software*, open Chromium details, click on *Permissions* and switch ON the following option :

> read/write files on removable storage devices

[image: like that]

Comment: How to do that with out GUI?